# Convert a list of tab prefixed strings to a dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

Text mining attempts here, I would like to turn the below:

```
  a=['Colors.of.the universe:\n',
     '   Black: 111\n',
     '   Grey: 222\n',
     '   White: 11\n'
     'Movies of the week:\n',
     '   Mission Impossible: 121\n',
     '   Die_Hard: 123\n',
     '   Jurassic Park: 33\n',
     'Lands.categories.said:\n',
     '   Desert: 33212\n',
     '   forest: 4532\n',
     '   grassland : 431\n',
     '   tundra : 243451\n']
```

to this:

```
{'Colors.of.the universe':{Black:111,Grey:222,White:11},
 'Movies of the week':{Mission Impossible:121,Die_Hard:123,Jurassic Park:33},
 'Lands.categories.said': {Desert:33212,forest:4532,grassland:431,tundra:243451}}
```

Tried this code below but it was not good:

```
{words[1]:words[1:] for words in a}
```

which gives

```
{'o': 'olors.of.the universe:\n',
 ' ': '  tundra : 243451\n',
 'a': 'ands.categories.said:\n'}
```

It only takes the first word as the key which is not what's needed.

A dict comprehension is an interesting approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = ['Colors.of.the universe:\n',
     '   Black: 111\n',
     '   Grey: 222\n',
     '   White: 11\n',
     'Movies of the week:\n',
     '   Mission Impossible: 121\n',
     '   Die_Hard: 123\n',
     '   Jurassic Park: 33\n',
     'Lands.categories.said:\n',
     '   Desert: 33212\n',
     '   forest: 4532\n',
     '   grassland : 431\n',
     '   tundra : 243451\n']

result = dict()
current_key = None
for w in a:
    # If starts with tab - its an item (under category)
    if w.startswith('   '):
        # Splitting item (i.e. '   Desert: 33212\n' -> ['   Desert', ' 33212\n']
        splitted = w.split(':')
        # Setting the key and the value of the item
        # Removing redundant spaces and '\n'
        # Converting value to number
        k, v = splitted[0].strip(), int(splitted[1].replace('\n', ''))
        result[current_key][k] = v
    # Else, it's a category
    else:
        # Removing ':' and '\n' form category name
        current_key = w.replace(':', '').replace('\n', '')
        # If category not exist - create a dictionary for it
        if not current_key in result.keys():
            result[current_key] = {}

# {'Colors.of.the universe': {'Black': 111, 'Grey': 222, 'White': 11}, 'Movies of the week': {'Mission Impossible': 121, 'Die_Hard': 123, 'Jurassic Park': 33}, 'Lands.categories.said': {'Desert': 33212, 'forest': 4532, 'grassland': 431, 'tundra': 243451}}
print(result)
```

Comment: Here you go @saZ, no external library :)

Answer (score 0):

That's *really close* to valid YAML already. You could just quote the property labels and parse. And parsing a known format is MUCH superior to dealing with and/or inventing your own. *Even if* you're just exploring base python, exploring *good practices* is just as (probably more) important.

```
import re
import yaml

raw = ['Colors.of.the universe:\n',
     '   Black: 111\n',
     '   Grey: 222\n',
     '   White: 11\n',
     'Movies of the week:\n',
     '   Mission Impossible: 121\n',
     '   Die_Hard: 123\n',
     '   Jurassic Park: 33\n',
     'Lands.categories.said:\n',
     '   Desert: 33212\n',
     '   forest: 4532\n',
     '   grassland : 431\n',
     '   tundra : 243451\n']

# Fix spaces in property names
fixed = []
for line in raw:
     match = re.match(r'^( *)(\S.*?): ?(\S*)\s*', line)

     if match:
          fixed.append('{indent}{safe_label}:{value}'.format(
               indent = match.group(1),
               safe_label = "'{}'".format(match.group(2)),
               value = ' ' + match.group(3) if match.group(3) else ''
          ))
     else:
          raise Exception("regex failed")

parsed = yaml.load('\n'.join(fixed), Loader=yaml.FullLoader)

print(parsed)
```